# Memory issue in Windows Phone Page Transition

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit

In order to implement page transition in my application i added the toolkit turnstile animation, Before adding the transition the app was stable and i didn’t face any memory issues. After implementing the toolkit transition animation the memory is increasing like Everest. I think while the time of transition the memory releasing is not takes places, Can any one please suggest a solution for me to resolve this issue, or guide me to implement turnstile animation in an alternative way in my app. Hope many of them may face this issue and solved. So please help me. ThanX in advance

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691413/windows-phone-7-page-transitions-very-slow-using-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

What do you call "toolkit turnstile application" ? 
Windows Phone 7 uses navigation transitions, you can find the way to do it here on [Windows Phone Geek](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide).
Navigation transitions works well, if you are already using them,  I think that the performance issue came from your code, maybe some overload in the NavigateFrom/To events.
If you are not already using them, please give a try ;)

Comment: For ur kind  knowledge, Toolkit transition had memory issues its not because of my code. And one more thng, From mango app onwards MS implemented a tool called marketplace test kit, hop you know, if we try to implement animation on a heavily data holding  page. It will took lots of time to load, as per marketplace requirement the app not take more than 5 sec  for loading, primarily this will violate. And also there cause issues in white theme support. Simply gave a try with sample app, u can realise the scenario.

Comment: Sorry if I offenced you in any way, that was not the purpose (I got some issues writing in english). I thought that memory issues was corrected by the august version of the Toolkit. 
As an alternative of the Toolkit's turnstile transition, there is a free solution here http://turnstile.codeplex.com/ but I do not know its impact in application performance.

Comment: But from my research only i conclude that, its having issues with transition, For to make u clear, better you create a panorama application that contains 2-4 pages. And apply the toolkit animation to that and check the performance. I am not concern with the application usual behaviour instead you please try the market place test kit and see the difference. Microsoft is considering this tools result as benchmark. I still forced to believe that, even that testing tool itself have plenty issues

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the original toolkit for windows phone but the 7.1 version of the toolkit solved the transitions memory issues. It may also have something to do with mango's generational garbage collector being much more efficient at removing items from memory sooner.

In WP7.0 I tracked it down to the transition requiring both pages to be in memory at the same time in order for the transition to look correct. I think the new version may use a writeable bitmap (just speculation) for the page that is transitioning out - there was atleast 2x speed increase with the upgraded toolkit and memory issues were all but eliminated.